# How do I disable "Supply power" over USB?

Tags: usb, charging

With my Nexus 5x connected to a desktop PC over USB: when powering down the desktop I've noticed the phone switches from "Use USB to just charge this device" to "Use USB to supply power to the other connected device". On one occasion this appears to have drained the phone battery.

Is it possible to disable the "Use USB to supply power" option?